# Does exercise make you healthier?

Tags: disease, physical-fitness, causality

It is widely believed that regular exercise helps people become fitter, stronger and healthier. For example, from [Physical Activity Guidelines for Americans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Activity_Guidelines_for_Americans#Health_benefits_of_regular_physical_activity):

> **Regular physical activity is one of the most important things you can do for your health**. It can help: [...] reduce your risk of cardiovascular disease; reduce your risk for type 2 diabetes and metabolic syndrome; reduce your risk of some cancers; strengthen your bones and muscles; improve your mental health and mood; improve your ability to do daily activities and prevent falls, if you're an older adult; increase your chances of living longer.

Indeed, there is plenty of evidence that exercise is *correlated* with lower incidence of various diseases.

However, it could be that people who are born naturally healthy (and have a genetically lower risk of these diseases) also are genetically coded to have more energy, and therefore exercise more.

Put another way, somebody who is sick and tired all the time is less likely to exercise, but this doesn't mean the lack of exercise caused their illness.

Is there any convincing evidence that this is a **causal relationship** from exercise to health, e.g. from randomized controlled trials? I am not interested in observational studies that show people who exercise are healthier - that much is very clear. I am interested in studies that prove that exercise directly causes health benefits such as those claimed above.

Comment: > Does exercise make you healthier, or do healthy people just exercise more? Both could be true.

Comment: I don't think this is quite enough for an answer (very small sample size, news article), but maybe a route to research on are twin studies. See this [article](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/03/04/one-twin-exercises-the-other-doesnt/?_r=0) for instance.

Comment: This has been flagged as containing no notable claim, but I think it is a widely-believed claim that doing exercise makes you healthier. Should be easy to prove with some randomised trials. (I remember hearing an experimenter reporting difficulties because members of a control group, having been enrolled in an exercise experiment, and then left alone with no treatment, became self-motivated by the neglect to increase their daily exercise themselves!)

Comment: @georgechalhoub: I see the notable claim as "exercise makes you healthy", and John being skeptical about it, arguing correlation doesn't equal causation, and showing an inverse relationship is plausible. I am confident someone will post a randomised controlled trial which will demonstrate causality.

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub: Done.

Comment: What kind of exercises? Healthier in what way? This question is as vague as it gets. I can't really see how it could be answered in its current form. Widely-believed claim isn't defined enough to be checked scientifically.

Comment: On the other hand there's a ton of evidence that *lack* of exercise is *unhealthy*, in a casual manner. E.g. Sitting increases the risk of embolism.

Comment: How would one measure health exactly?

Comment: @Oddthinking I think that this title edit detracts from the point of the question and will lead to more answers demonstrating correlation not cause. The whole point is whether our belief that exercise is so healthy could be based on the fact that healthy people just exercise more.

Comment: I've put it on hold why we resolve the arguments over what the problem is. John: I think you are going to have to find a specific notable claim to resolve this.

Comment: @Oddthinking I searched this site for 'healthy' which shows hundreds of questions of the form "is x healthy". Would it help to quote the claims from Wikipedia like http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/is-a-vegetarian-vegan-diet-more-healthy?

Comment: I think it would, but then again, I thought this question would be quickly dispatched with evidence of causality, so who am I to judge :-)

Comment: @Oddthinking Does [Physical activity has been shown to reduce the risk of over 25 chronic conditions](http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/hp-ps/hl-mvs/pa-ap/02paap-eng.php) fit the bill, i.e. does that statement imply a causal relationship? And/or there's [advice on how much physical activity is generally recommended to realize health benefits](http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/hp-ps/hl-mvs/pa-ap/03paap-eng.php) which IMO implies that the amount of exercise is a choice (not something you're just born with nor a pre-determined consequence of health), and that health benefits are a (caused) consequence.

Comment: @Oddthinking Done, requesting to re-open :-)

Answer (score 44):

### Besides,

### taking away your stress

exercise is [proven](http://www.princeton.edu/main/news/archive/S37/28/70Q72/index.xml?section=topstories) to increase concentrations of norepinephrine, a chemical that can moderate the brain’s response to stress.

### and boosting happy chemicals

usually within five minutes after moderate exercise you [get](http://www.apa.org/monitor/2011/12/exercise.aspx) a mood-enhancement effect.

### and alleviating long-term depression

data suggests that active people are less depressed than inactive people, those who were active and [stopped](http://www.apa.org/monitor/2011/12/exercise.aspx) tend to be more depressed than those who maintain or initiate an exercise program

### and improving your self-confidence

regardless of weight, sexual orientation, gender, or age, exercise can quickly elevate a person's perception of his or her attractiveness: [self-confidence and self-worth](http://psychcentral.com/news/2009/03/19/exercise-improves-self-esteem-in-overweight-kids/4839.html).

### and preventing cognitive decline

exercising boosts the chemicals in the brain that support and prevent degeneration of the [hippocampus](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/30/15/5368.abstract), an important part of the brain for memory and learning, which would prevent Alzheimer.

### and reducing anxiety

the warm and fuzzy chemicals that are released after exercise can help people with [anxiety disorders](http://www.adaa.org/living-with-anxiety/managing-anxiety/exercise-stress-and-anxiety) calm down

### and help controlling addiction

we all are addicted to something, right? Whether it is drugs, alcohol, internet, food or sex, exercise can help in [addiction recovery](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2829243/)

### and unleashing your creativity

It is reported that one gym session can boost creativity for up to [two hours afterwards](http://www.ric.edu/faculty/dblanchette/exercisearticle.htm).

### and reducing the chances of developing heart disease, stroke, and diabetes

It is reported by over [11 scientific articles](http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/staying-active-full-story/#references) that bicycling and walking reduce your chance of getting all those diseases.

### and making you lose weight

[you](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17557987) [don't](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12525233) [need](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20591106) [evidence](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3406229/) [for](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19127177) [that](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20083615)? [do](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15925949) [you](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25606816)?

### and promoting better sleep

regular physical activity can help you [fall asleep faster](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/fitness/in-depth/exercise/art-20048389?pg=2) and sharpen your sleep.

### and lowering risk of all the following

[up](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/fitness/Pages/Whybeactive.aspx) [to a 35% lower risk of coronary heart disease and stroke](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/216370/dh_128210.pdf) and *up to a 50% lower risk of type 2 diabetes* and *up to a 50% lower risk of colon cancer* and *[up to a 20% lower risk of breast cancer](http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/34/Supplement_2/S210.full)* and *[a 30% lower risk of early death](http://fitness.mercola.com/sites/fitness/archive/2010/08/20/physical-activity-reduces-the-risk-of-early-death.aspx)* and *[up to an 83% lower risk of osteoarthritis](http://www.excarbs.com/why-exercise/)* and *up to a 68% lower risk of hip fracture* and *a 30% lower risk of falls (among older adults)* and *[up to a 30% lower risk of depression](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15626549)* and *[up to a 30% lower risk of dementia](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2738400/)*

### and preventing osteoporosis

Weight-bearing exercises, like running, walking and weight-lifting, help lower your odds of getting [osteoporosis](http://nof.org/exercise) as you grow older

### and reducing the severity of asthma

swimming is one of the best exercises for people with asthma, [exercise](http://www.aaaai.org/conditions-and-treatments/library/asthma-library/asthma-and-exercise.aspx)  helps in fewer or milder asthma attacks overall and a need for less medication.

### and promoting a healthy pregnancy

Relaxation exercises and Kegel exercise that strengthen the pelvic muscles and back [exercises](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/pregnancy-week-by-week/multimedia/pregnancy-exercises/sls-20076779) are all important for pregnant women.

### and having anti-ageing effects

exercise might be the best [anti-ageing](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22429905.300-exercise-may-be-the-best-antiageing-pill.html#.VRU_lJOUc4Q) pill according to many scientists.

### and improving your sex life

The medical research [points](http://www.ejhs.org/volume7/fitness.html) towards it: the fitter you are, the better your sex life is.

### and ignoring the fact that physical inactivity is twice as deadly as obesity

from recent [report](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/20150114/lack-of-exercise-more-deadly-than-obesity-study-suggests) by the American Journal of Clinical Nutrition.

### there is no evidence that exercise makes you healthier at all.

**UPDATE:**

The OP updated his question saying he's asking about **causation** and not **correlation**.

It seems:

### 1) there is a lack of evidence that a causal link between physical exercise and good mental health exists.

This [book](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=-HXeZsX2L0sC&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=causal+relationship+from+exercise+to+health&source=bl&ots=YDWwDQwtdS&sig=7iwwSQzQnRGdIqrFTQkihKmYwJM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SxMbVZbeF8KdsAGon4PQDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=causal%20relationship%20from%20exercise%20to%20health&f=false) called ***Workplace Health: Employee Fitness And Exercise*** provides a great summary to a series of studies which concluded that there is a lack of causal relationship between physical exercise and mental health.

[image]

In another large cross-sectional research<sup>(1)</sup>, scientists and researchers were able to prove that physical exercise is correlated with lower risk of depression, however, fortunately for people against physical exercise, they couldn't prove a causal link between the two, researchers said they:

> are not able to make any firm conclusions on the direction of causation in any of the associations described

NHS [blogged](http://www.nhs.uk/news/2010/11November/pages/exercise-linked-to-lower-depression.aspx) about the study and said:

> In general, **this study adds to the evidence that exercise is good for mental health**, although in isolation **it does not prove a causal link between the two**. It should be discussed in the context of what else is known about the benefits of exercise.

---

Digging deeper, I found that, according to a [governmental report](http://www.cdc.gov/nccdphp/sgr/pdf/chap4.pdf):

### 2) there is a causal link between physical exercise and reduction in risk in all-cause mortality, all CVDs combined, CHD, hypertension, colon cancer, and NIDDM.

> **Causality**
>
> The studies reviewed in this chapter indicate that
>   **physical activity** is associated with a reduction in risk
>   of **all-cause mortality**, **all CVDs combined**, **CHD**,
>   **hypertension**, **colon cancer**, and **NIDDM**.
>
> To evaluate whether the information presented is sufficient to
>   infer that these associations are causal in nature, **it is
>   useful to review the evidence according to Hill’s
>   classic criteria for causality** (Hill 1965; Paffenbarger
>   1988).
>
> *Strength of Association.* The numerous estimated
>   measures of association for cardiovascular outcomes
>   presented in this chapter generally **fall within the
>   range of a 1.5- to 2.0-fold increase in risk of adverse
>   health outcomes associated with inactivity**. This
>   range represents a **moderately strong association**,
>   similar in magnitude to the relationship between
>   CHD and smoking, hypertension, or elevated cholesterol.
>   The associations with NIDDM, hypertension,
>   and colon cancer have been somewhat smaller
>   in magnitude. The difficulty in measuring physical
>   activity may lead to substantial misclassification,
>   which in turn would bias studies toward finding less
>   of an effect of activity than may actually exist. On the
>   other hand, not controlling for all potential confounders
>   could bias studies toward finding more of
>   an effect than may actually exist. Efforts to stratify
>   studies of physical activity and CHD by the quality of measurement have found that the methodologically
>   **better studies showed larger associations than those
>   with lower quality scores** (Powell et al. 1987; Berlin
>   and Colditz 1990). In addition, **cardiorespiratory
>   fitness, which is more objectively and precisely measured
>   than the reported level of physical activity,
>   often is also more strongly related to CVD and
>   mortality**. Measures of association between physical
>   activity and health outcomes thus might be stronger if
>   physical activity measurements were more accurate.
>   Consistency of Findings. Although the epidemiologic
>   studies of physical activity have varied greatly
>   in methodology, in ways of classifying physical activity,
>   and in populations studied, **the findings have
>   been remarkably consistent in supporting a reduction
>   in risk as a function of greater amounts of
>   physical activity, or conversely, an increase in risk as
>   a function of inactivity**.
>
> *Temporality.* For most of the health conditions
>   included in this chapter (all-cause mortality, CVD,
>   CHD, hypertension, NIDDM), **longitudinal data from
>   cohort studies have been available and have confirmed
>   a temporal sequence in which physical activity
>   patterns are determined prior to development of
>   disease**. For obesity and mental health, fewer longitudinal
>   studies have been conducted, and findings
>   have been more equivocal. **Perhaps the strongest
>   evidence for temporality comes from two studies of
>   the effect of changes in activity or fitness level.** Men
>   who became more active or more fit had a lower
>   mortality rate during follow-up than men who remained
>   inactive or unfit (Paffenbarger et al. 1993;
>   Blair et al. 1995).
>
> *Biological Gradient.* **Studies of all-cause mortality,
>   CVD, CHD, and NIDDM have shown a gradient
>   of greater benefit associated with higher amounts of
>   physical activity.** Most studies that included more
>   than two categories of amount of physical activity
>   and were therefore able to evaluate a dose-response
>   relationship **found a gradient of decreasing risk of
>   disease with increasing amounts of physical activity**
>   (see Tables 4-1 through 4-8).
>
> *Biologic Plausibility.*
>   Evidence that physiologic effects of physical activity have beneficial consequences
>   for CHD, NIDDM, and obesity is abundant
>   (see Chapter 3, as well as the biologic plausibility
>   sections of this chapter). **Such evidence includes
>   beneficial effects on physiologic risk factors for
>   disease, such as high blood pressure and blood
>   lipoproteins, as well as beneficial effects on circulatory
>   system functioning, blood-clotting mechanisms,
>   insulin production and glucose handling,
>   and caloric balance.**
>
> *Experimental Evidence.* Controlled clinical trials
>   have not been conducted for the outcomes of mortality,
>   CVD, cancer, obesity, or NIDDM. However,
>   randomized clinical trials have determined that
>   **physical activity improves these diseases’ risk factors,
>   such as blood pressure, lipoprotein profile,
>   insulin sensitivity, and body fat.**
>
> The information reviewed in this chapter shows
>   that the **inverse association between physical activity
>   and several diseases is moderate in magnitude**, consistent
>   across studies that differed substantially in
>   methods and populations, and biologically plausible.
>   A dose-response gradient has been observed in
>   most studies that examined more than two levels of
>   activity. For most of the diseases found to be inversely
>   related to physical activity, **the temporal
>   sequence of exposure preceding disease has been
>   demonstrated.** Although controlled clinical trials
>   have not been conducted (and are not likely to be
>   conducted) for morbidity and mortality related to
>   the diseases of interest, controlled trials have shown
>   that activity can improve physiologic risk factors for
>   these diseases.

> **From this large body of consistent information, it is reasonable to conclude that physical activity is causally related to the health outcomes reported here**.

References:

<sup>Layman, E. M. (1960). Contribution of exercise and sport to mental health and social adjustment. In Science and medicine of exercise and sports, ed. W.R. Johnson, New York</sup>

<sup>Cureton, T. K. (1963) Improvement of  psychological state by means of exercise programs. Journal of the Association for Physical and mental rehabilitation, 17, 14-25.</sup>

<sup>Chernen, L., FRIEDMAN, S., GOLDBERG, N., FEIT, A., KWAT, T. and STEIN, R. (1995) Cardiac disease and ...</sup>

<sup>Morgan, W.P. and O'Connor, P. J. (1988) Exercise and mental health. In Exercise adherence: its impact on public health, ed. R.K. DISHMAN. Champaign.</sup>

<sup>(1) Harvey SB, Hotopf M et al. [Physical activity and common mental disorders.](http://bjp.rcpsych.org/cgi/content/abstract/197/5/357) The British Journal of Psychiatry (2010) 197: 357-364</sup>

Comment: 486 words of pure, unfiltered sarcasm. Would you mind providing references to the part *and lowering risk of all the following*?

Comment: It it not shown that despite those factors, exercise makes you no healthier.  I suggest rephrasing it as *besides (...), there is no evidence that exercise makes you healthier at all*.

Comment: Ah - but to play complete devil's advocate, presumably exercise could also have negative results (higher injury rates, perhaps)?  Would these automatically be smaller than the benefits?

Comment: @xorsyst I think I read an article recently suggesting that there is an "optimum" amount of exercise (jogging was the type tested) that you can do, and doing more *or* less is worse for your health. So the negatives are not automatically outweighed, but they are outweighed for light/moderate exercise. (Disclaimer: I don't know how the research was done, who did it, what the response was academically, how much tends to be optimal, etc.)

Comment: The question explicitly argues that correlation is insufficient. The question is about causality. Generally, this requires randomised controlled trials (ideally double-blinded, placebo-controlled, although I'm not sure what that entails here). Not all of your references support that (I spot-checked. First and last references are examples.)

Comment: Why does it need to be sarcastic? It's unpleasant to read and it sounds like you have an agenda, instead of providing unbiased factual information.

Comment: @Oddthinking I can't upvote your comment, but this is exactly the point I am trying to make - observational evidence is not sufficient to prove cause and effect. We need to select subjects randomly for intervention and compare with controls. From the references I checked, this answer misses the point.

Comment: "and boosting happy chemicals" which is why absolutely every kid in school loves P.E./Gym class. None of them ever try to get out of it.

Comment: Exercise is not really a good or practical way to lose weight. You do need to reference that.

Comment: @georgechalhoub Sadly nobody has P.E./gym lessons like that. If they did we'd need a massive supply of chandeliers. Also if all of these studies are true, presumably A) I should be in really poor health and B) being more active would magically make everything in my life better.

Comment: @georgechalhoub The first reference shows that exercise makes you lose weight, not that it is a good and practical way to do so. The second shows that indeed it's a good way of keeping your fat free mass, but only has moderate results in terms of weight loss compared to calorie restriction. In either case, exercise is not a practical way to lose weight.

Comment: Also, you need to address over-exercise.

Comment: You should address it because you are making your answer worse by choosing the wrong tone, addressing only one side and making imprecise assertions. Furthermore, nobody forces you to answer it if you think it's to broad, and your comments regarding it are not pleasing to read nor accurate. Did you vote to close this question?

Comment: @George: I think you may not have understood my concern. Any of the references (not just the first and last, but others including (not limited) to the "heart disease, stroke, and diabetes" entry) which are not referring to randomised controlled experiments cannot (practically) prove that exercise is the cause of healthy outcomes (rather than exercise is merely associated with healthy outcomes). The new final reference is to a survey - that cannot prove causality.

Comment: IMO you could delete this because it doesn't answer the question, because the whole purpose of the question was to ask whether there's a causal relationship.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22369/discussion-on-answer-by-georgechalhoub-does-exercise-make-you-healthier).