# Does dairy milk and meat decrease your overall health and make you live less?

Tags: nutrition, mortality, vegetarianism

In this [extremely popular and numerously mirrored lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV-mlTfM070), Dr. Michael Greger presents "proofs" that humans should not consume dairy milk and meat at all, because it is destructive to health in numerous aspects, and by drinking it we effectively shorten our lifespan.

For example, re. cancer, between time 20:58 and 21:30 he asks "how low does our consumption of animal products have to go?" and answers that "only vegans" (not "vegetarians" or "meat-eaters") have significantly lower levels of circulating IGF-1.

Are dairy milk and meat destructive to human health? Does the average human live longer if dairy milk and meat is abstained?

Comment: This is a 55 minute video. Can you please transcribe a relevant quote, with a timecode, so we don't all have to watch the entire video to find it?

Comment: The lecture includes arguments like, people die of heart attacks when they're measured as having normal or optimal levels of cholesterol ... therefore the "normal" level of cholesterol is too high. So it's a complicated message with several parts to it.

Comment: @oddthinking: That's a good point, there are so many claims in that video. I was considering quoting the relevant parts and putting them in a list.

Comment: I'm wary of lists, because it often makes it too broad to answer. Pick one, and then ask separate questions for the others.

Comment: In that case, the single question would be "Do meat and milk make you live less", which is what the question currently is.

Comment: The lecture does have more one claim. For example the lecture starts by saying that **heart disease** might be caused by meat-based bacterial toxins being carried into the body via animal fat, whereas the next part of the lecture is about **cancer** being attributable to IGF-1.

Comment: I changed milk to "dairy milk" because it is non-vegan (soy milk is) and it what the author implies.

Comment: Your quoted claim is about vegans and IGF-1. Your subject title is about milk/meat and living "less" (presumably you mean dying earlier). We already have a question about whether the [vegan diet is healthier](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/is-a-vegetarian-vegan-diet-more-healthy). We need a quote that includes a claim, and a title that matches the claim, and for it not to be a duplicate.

Comment: @oddthinking: You are right, it's essentially an identical question. Feel free to mark as duplicate.